# An expression of non-boolean type specified ... sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-in

```
select sp_name, office, comm 
from sperson
where (office,comm) in (select office, min(comm) from sperson group by office);
```

This works in Oracle and MySQL.

Comment: SQL Server does not support that syntax

Answer (score 1):

You need subquery with *correlation* & the SQL Server would support syntax :

```
select sp.*
from sperson sp
where comm = (select min(sp1.comm)
              from sperson sp1
              where sp1.office = sp.office
             );
```

However, this could also achieve via `row_number()`/`dense_rank()` function :

```
select top (1) with ties sp.*
from sperson sp
order by row_number() over (partition by office order by comm);
```